# How would I modify this Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I have purchased the Imagpress theme and I have been able to modify the structure using Firebug but I cannot workout where to add the modifications needed.

It is [home 5](http://themeforest.net/item/imagpress-flat-magazine-theme-/full_screen_preview/6052835)

[image]

I have deleted the top menu in firebug and modified margins etc.

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Comment: The margins would be edited in the css and the menu can be removed in the header file (or removing all items in the menu option)

Comment: Are you editing a website using firebug? lol

Comment: Hi im not using firebug to modify it just to see the changes lol.

Comment: What piece of code would I need to modify to take out the top menu? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option to add custom CSS to the theme that will over ride the styles. Normally found in your theme settings. If there is not a custom CSS area, you can access the CSS somewhere around *Appearance > Editor*. If you then navigate to `style.css` you can apply changes there.

[image: Editor Location (WordPress 3.8.1)]

However using this method will undo changes made if you update your theme, I would suggest using a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) :) There are several benefits to using Child Themes, a few are:

- Modifications to CSS will be not be reverted if the Theme is updated
- Allows the user to experiment with the design of the Theme without potentially destroying the original code!

I won't mention any more as they can all be found in the link provided. Hope this helps!